# How can I clean up text after google translate?

Tags: php

```
Lipsește + valoare + pentru argument + +% 23% 251% 24s% 3A +% 3Cstrong% 3E% 253% 24s% 3C% 2Fstrong% 3E + clasa + +% 3Cstrong% 3E% 252% 24s% 3C% 2Fstrong% 3E% 5B% 3C% 23% 3E% 5DNo + controler + a fost + + specificat.% 5B% 3C% 23% 3E% 5DNo + metoda + a fost + specificată + pentru + + controler.% 5B% 3C% 23% 3E% 5DThe + serviciu + pentru + controler +%% E2 80% 9C% 3Cstrong% 3E% 25s% 3C% 2Fstrong% 3E% E2% 80% 9D + nu + definit + in +.% 2Fconfig% 2Fservices.yml.
```

We should get someting like this:

```
Lipsește valoare pentru argumentul #%1$s: %3$s în clasa %2$sNu a fost specificat controlerul.Nu a fost specificată metoda pentru controler.Serviciul pentru controlerul “%s” nu este definit în ./config/services.yml.
```

Comment: Use the php built in function **urldecode()**?

Comment: Yes it works but there are more to do:   $data = str_replace('% ', '%', $data); 
  $data = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $data);
  $data = str_replace('>', '&gt;', $data);
  $data = str_replace('<', '&lt;', $data);

  $data = str_replace("\n", '&#10;', $data);
  $data = str_replace("\r", '&#13;', $data);
  $data = str_replace("\t", '&#9;', $data);
  
  $data = urldecode($data);